# What does ~ and ^ mean before version number after module name in composer.json?

Tags: magento2.3, module

Sorry for this newbie question:

What does ~ and ^ mean before version number after module name in composer.json ?

"mageplaza/module-core": "^1.4.1"

"sebastian/phpcpd": "~3.0.0"

Answer (score 1):

> Tilde Version Range (~)

> The ~ operator is best explained by example:
> ~1.2 is equivalent to >=1.2 <2.0.0, while ~1.2.3 is equivalent to
> `>=1.2.3 <1.3.0.` As you can see it is mostly useful for projects respecting semantic versioning. **A common usage would be to mark the
> minimum minor version you depend on**, like ~1.2 (which allows anything
> up to, but not including, 2.0). Since in theory there should be no
> backwards compatibility breaks until 2.0, that works well. Another way
> of looking at it is that using ~ specifies a minimum version, but
> allows the last digit specified to go up.
>
> Example: ~1.2
>
> Note: Although 2.0-beta.1 is strictly before 2.0, a version constraint
> like ~1.2 would not install it. As said above ~1.2 only means the .2
> can change but the 1. part is fixed.
>
> Note: The ~ operator has an exception on its behavior for the major
> release number. This means for example that ~1 is the same as ~1.0 as
> it will not allow the major number to increase trying to keep
> backwards compatibility.

---

> Caret Version Range (^)

> **The ^ operator behaves very similarly, but it
> sticks closer to semantic versioning, and will always allow
> non-breaking updates**. For example ^1.2.3 is equivalent to >=1.2.3
> <2.0.0 as none of the releases until 2.0 should break backwards
> compatibility. For pre-1.0 versions it also acts with safety in mind
> and treats ^0.3 as >=0.3.0 <0.4.0.
>
> This is the recommended operator for maximum interoperability when
> writing library code.
>
> Example: ^1.2.3

Taken from https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#tilde-version-range-